# Authentication in MVC/angular hybrid using ASP.NET Identity Framework 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

So we have an angular-based "mini-SPA" app which uses ASP.NET Identity Framework 2 for authentication/authorization. This is fine - we can read the bearer token and all is well. However for some functionality we need to have the user access a 'raw' MVC style route. Say we need to render an HTML view as a pdf and can't do this with client-side rendering. In that case authorization fails because the bearer token is not set by the browser. The cookies containing the relevant authorization data are present but not read. Question is, how do we authenticate/authorize those requests? We've though of the hacky method of saving the bearer token in a cookie then using an HttpModule to read it out again, but there has to be a proper way to do this...

Comment: You can use standard forms authentication method for non ajax requests.

Comment: That doesn't help though. We need to authenticate them against the same credentials, seamlessly. Unless I'm missing something...